# Excel VBA: Advanced Filter, how to display a MsgBox when no match found

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question around Advanced Filters. I'm trying to figure out how to have a MsgBox Error message when the filter doesn't find a match.

I've put a comment within the first Sub (FilterData) where I thought the error message should go

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub FilterData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    Dim CriteriaRange As Range
    Set CriteriaRange = ws.Range("J2", "L3")

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A5", "I" & LastRow)

'This is where I thought I needed the OnError, but it shows the error message on every execution regardless of whether a match is found or not

On Error GoTo NoQuickFound
    DataRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=CriteriaRange, Unique:=False

NoQuickFound:
MsgBox "No match"

End Sub
```

```
Public Sub ShowAll()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub GetNextResult()
    FilterData






    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")


    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A5", "I" & LastRow) 

    Dim FilteredData As Range
    Set FilteredData = DataRange.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If CurrentRow + 1 > FilteredData.Cells.Count Then
        CurrentRow = 1
    End If

    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Cell As Variant
    For Each Cell In FilteredData
        i = i + 1
        If i = CurrentRow Then
            Call ShowAll

            TextboxName = "Box1"
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName).DrawingObject.Text = Cell.Offset(0, 2)

            TextboxName2 = "Box2"
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName2).DrawingObject.Text = Cell.Offset(0, 3)


            Call quick_artwork
        End If
    Next Cell
```

It is made up of 3 subs:

FilterData = Actually does the filtering of the results, this is where I expect I need to put the error message if it doesn't find a match

ShowAll = This resets the filtered results so it shows everything

GetNextResult = My spreadsheet doesn't actually show the filtered results, it replaces 2 text boxes with the values from the filter result and changes on every execution

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple condition like this will work:**

```
If Not DataRange.Columns(1).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then

    MsgBox "No Results"

End If
```

**Code:**

```
Public Sub FilterData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row


    Dim CriteriaRange As Range
    Set CriteriaRange = ws.Range("J2", "L3")

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A5", "I" & LastRow)

    DataRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=CriteriaRange, Unique:=False

    If Not DataRange.Columns(1).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then

        MsgBox "No Results"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mikku - thanks for your help

I've put in your code exactly and despite it containing the match upon execution, it still prompts the MsgBox error (it executes everything else as it should, but the prompt appears when it shouldn't)

Comment: Hi, I have changed the code a Bit. Can you try again. Also, are you sure there are results in the Autofilter ? @Sam

Comment: I’ll be back at my computer in about an hour to check, but regarding your question around if there are results: it does actually show the right results, it’s just it also shows the MsgBox even though it has results

Comment: No worries, just try and let me know. It should work though now.

Comment: Took a little longer until I was able to test it. So when I run your code, if it finds a match it works normally now. If it doesn't find a match it shows the MsgBox but then it prompts with a Run-time error 6 Overflow - which highlight this line of code `If CurrentRow + 1 > FilteredData.Cells.Count Then`  but I added a Exit Sub in there and it seemed to resolve the issue, so all is good now.

Comment: One thing I wanted to ask, I'm having this weird issue, I was thinking of posting it here on StackOverflow. The first time I execute this filter it returns the values of the header rather than the data below it. Every other time it executes only the data, without issue. But if I quit Excel and opened it again and executed it, it would show the headers. Any idea how I can avoid this? Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Probably you should ask another question for that. Including Screeshot of what you are getting. I can suggest that you run your Code using `F8` and check at every step what is happening. That resolves many issues.

Comment: I was trying to think of a workaround. Could there be a line of code that says "if the returned result is [header string] then go to next result" (obviously [header string] is the actual text of the header)

Comment: Fixed it, thought I'd leave this here in case anyone has a similar issue. `Dim header As String`, `header = "insert header title string"`, then inside the if statement where it places the filtered results into the textbook, I also put `If ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName).DrawingObject.Text = header Then` and then I had it repeat the same sub `Call GetNextResult`

Comment: Mikku, I'm now trying to change the Criteria to look for a a value ending in a variable. So if the last 4 digits of any row in column C matches the 4 digits entered in Textbox10 then it returns the filtered results - do you know if this can be done? Thanks

Comment: Hi Sam, please as a new question.@Sam

Comment: just posted it @Mikku - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57307428/excel-vba-advanced-filter-criteria-set-to-any-cell-containing-last-4-digits-en